# I have a Big Essay coming up. I need some help. The question is "Do we say Where she works or Where she is working?" These two are correct but its

Tags: american-english

I have a Big Essay coming up. I need some help. The question is "Do we say Where she works or Where she is working?" These two are correct but they're given as different answers. There is no way to know whether either is correct because there's no marking sheet.

Comment: If these are two possible answers in a multiple choice test, note that we don't usually accept questions on that basis. Also note that ***where she works*** and ***where she is working*** are both perfectly valid ***noun phrases***, but without the context of an actual ***sentence*** within which they might be used, there's no meaning to the idea of "choosing between them".

Comment: I'm voting to close this answer because there is no context. So, it's impossible to say anything more other than "both are correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...where she works"  is in the simple present tense.

"...where she is working" is in the present continuous tense.

Both of these are OK to use, but they have slightly different time frames, so you need to pick the correct one in context.

"**The place where she works...**" is her place of employment, she will be working there in the immediate future.

"**The place where she is working...**"  means just the place she is working /right now/, it may be temporary or change.

So,

"**The place where she is working this afternoon...**" is natural and the use of the present continuous reminds us that her workplace is temporary.

A speaker would be less likely to say "The place where she works this afternoon", and this may even be confusing or considered incorrect in context.

So, the correct answer depends on your sentence.